# Database Schema Migration on Azure with Git Deployment

Tags: database, git, azure, migration

I am looking for a means to use Git deployment on Windows Azure together with either their MySQL or other database solutions.

I need a means of migrating database schema changes as part of deployment - does Azure provide support for this without using Visual Studio or .NET.

Answer (score 4):

You basically want to use Azure as a Continuous Integration (CI) platform and my view is that Azure by itself just isn't there yet.

A basic git based CI scenario would involve the following steps.

1. Your src code and any database schema/data updates are pushed to a central git repository like GitHub. [Feature available]
2. GitHub would then push the updates to Azure. [Not supported in Azure until they support GitHub hooks]
3. Azure compiles and deploys the code. [Supported]
4. Azure updates the database from sql files pulled from the repo (remember, this needs to be automated). [Not supported]
5. Azure reports any error in running the database or web application. [Supported]
6. Azure runs user provided integration tests to check more thoroughly specific functionality and reports the status of those tests to the user [Not supported].
7. Azure allows you to roll back to a previous deployment snapshot [Partly supported. Snapshots are not based on git commits for instance].

I might be wrong on some of those points or new features might be added since I've written this. Corrections are very welcomed and I'll try to update the list accordingly.

Comment: #2 and #7 should now be supported.  I'm not sure if #4 (migrating a schema via git deploy) is supported

Comment: #4 is also supported now. I created a proof of concept that uses the databaseInitilizer as explained in the blog post [EF Code First Migrations to an Azure Cloud Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/09/ef-code-first-migrations-deployment-to-an-azure-cloud-service.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much experiences you have with Windows Azure Websites, however when you are creating a Windows Azure Websites, you have ability to use SQL Azure Database or MySQL cloud database directly integrated with your Windows Azure Websites.

So if you will use SQL Azure Database then there are several ways you can migrate your DB following the link here:

[Migrating Databases to Windows Azure SQL Database (formerly SQL Azure)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee730904.aspx)

To manage MySQL you can use Local Web Server to do it. The way I have done is to use PHP, the MySQL Command-Line Tool (part of MySQL), and a web server set up on my local machine, and that I have  enabled the PDO extension for MySQL. This way I can manager my MySQL directly from my own local machine and the details are explain at the bottom of this article:

[Create a PHP-MySQL Windows Azure web site and deploy using Git](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/tutorials/website-w-mysql-and-git/).

Also the SQL part you can write in Workbench if you use MySQL and Oracle SQL Developer if you use Oracle SQL.

Finally Git Deployment allows you to deploy your any kind of application directly to Windows Azure without using VSx.

Comment: Thanks, I believe I am currently doing what you mention on Azure. What I now want to do is be able to "version" my MySQL database schema along with Git deploys. For instance, say I deploy a new version of my site that includes a new table and the PHP to manage this - how can I have Azure automatically update my database schema both for the new deploy, and ideally reverse the changes if I rollback the deploy?

Comment: You may need to do it directly within your code like via PHPAdmin, git may not be a tool to manage your MySQL versions directly. You sure can write scripts in your code to update DB schema after every update Git can not do that for you.